# Multi level multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I realize my question is very broad but I'm looking for broad answers as well :)

I have 2 functions: `outer` and `inner`.

```py
import traceback
import multiprocessing

def inner():
    return "blah"

def outer():
    success: bool = True
    process_pool: multiprocessing.Pool = multiprocessing.Pool(XXX)
    try:
        process_pool.map(inner)
        process_pool.close()
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        print(traceback.print_exc())
        success = False
        process_pool.terminate()
    except KeyboardInterrupt as ex:
        print(ex)
        success = False
        process_pool.terminate()
    finally:
        process_pool.join()
    return success
```

I would now like to create a `space` function which would execute `outer` the same way `outer` executes `inner`.

```py
def space():
    success: bool = True
    process_pool: multiprocessing.Pool = multiprocessing.Pool(YYY)
    try:
        process_pool.map(outer)
        process_pool.close()
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        print(traceback.print_exc())
        success = False
        process_pool.terminate()
    except KeyboardInterrupt as ex:
        print(ex)
        success = False
        process_pool.terminate()
    finally:
        process_pool.join()
    return success
```

Let's assume I have 100 CPUs at my disposal. How would one go about setting up that `space` function ? Split between XXX and YYY (num of CPUs in each multiprocessed function) ? Is it wise to do it that way ?

Comment: do you mean 100 CPU's as you have a cluster with 100 nodes? or a CPU with 100 cores? If it's a cluster, distributing the work to each node is very dependent on the cluster architecture.

Comment: I haven't gotten to that level of details yet tbh. Could you describe how the choices are different for each architecture maybe ? Most likely I will multiply the nodes rather than the cores though if you have to choose one.

Comment: I think you need to go figure out more details if you want a good answer... really at this point the answer could be anything.. The only thing I can tell you at this moment is to not bother with significantly more concurrent processes per cpu than there are cpu cores (`Pool` by default will create as many worker processes as cpu cores, so multiple `Pool`s per cpu is likely to hurt performance)

Comment: maybe do some [reading](https://towardsdatascience.com/modern-parallel-and-distributed-python-a-quick-tutorial-on-ray-99f8d70369b8) on distributed computing...